# cantilever brakes have 1mm play in then is this normal?

Tags: cyclocross

My cantilever brakes have roughly 1mm movement in them and can be moved backwards and forwards very easily by hand.

Is this because the shoulder bolt is too long or should the setup have some extra washers in place to stop this?

Will braking be improved by changing this?

Comment: This is not terribly uncommon, nor is it usually a problem.  If it bugs you, you can find "shim washers" at a hardware store to remove the play.  The only thing to check for is to make sure you don't have removable studs that have come partly unscrewed.

Comment: So changing it wont improve braking at all?

Comment: Unlikely to help - better pads and/or better brakes+levers are the way to go.